# Why/how is browser inserting inline SVGs at end of body?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, injection, browser-extensions, svg

Chrome is inserting the following SVG images at the bottom of pages:

```
<span style="width: 24px; height: 24px; background: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;) 50% 50% / 14px 14px no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; border: none; border-radius: 12px;"></span>
<span style="width: 24px; height: 24px; background: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;) 50% 50% / 14px 14px no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; border: none; border-radius: 12px; top: 5142px; left: 1901px;"></span>
```

Only noticed it because I had the dev panel open, and knew the page's code well enough to know they weren't supposed to be there. I confirmed it was happening to all sites after I found it on my own site. It's not present on tabs that'd been open for a couple of days, but appeared if I refreshed them.

Restarting the browser has stopped the behavior, at least for now.

The fact that the second SVG was positioning itself way offscreen and z-indexed high certainly seems like the actions of something malicious.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not Chrome itself doing this, but a browser extension. Extensions can be given permission to modify the content of open pages - this is usually needed for them to be able to do whatever they were designed to do. Off course, a malicious extension could also use this permission for all sorts of evil.

So what extension is this and is it malicious? I have no idea. You'll need to check what extensions you have installed. If you only have extensions you installed yourself and that you trust, everything is probably fine. However, if you find some unknown extension it might be a sign of a virus infection.

This is what the image looks like (on a grey background). If you recognice it as a UI element from some extension you use, I'd say everything is fine.

[image: Rendering of SVG image]